# Azure SNS Notifications - Email Subscriptions equivalent in Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-sns

I want to send notifications via email through Azure function apps. In AWS we have SNS, using boto3 we can send notifications to a particular topic and all the subscribers for that topic will receive notifications. Is there any similar kind of service in Azure that helps to send notifications to topics.